# Regex to check whether a string contains only numbers (including floating and negative numbers)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g`, it works ok, but it matches for '+++' for example.
So I need it to match +123, -89.56, but return false for '+', '-'
How should I change it to make it work?

Comment: Do you have to use regex or may i.e. use `Number(string)`?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: something like this: [+-]?[\d]?[\.]?[\d]+

Comment: @lvil Your regular expression doesn't allow numbers less tan -10.0 or greater than +10.0 if it has a fractional part. There is no need to put a single dot in a character class (and no need to escape a dot inside a character class) `[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?`

Comment: @some, your regex will not pass 13. (thirteen point).  To pass that you need to add some alternation.  Also this regex passes an empty string.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer It is intentionally not accepting "13.". If you write the point you have to write at least one decimal. The empty string is also intentionally accepted, since the value could be optional. If you want to be more strict, you should also add anchors and require at least one digit before the point: `^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$`. Note that it will match a number that is outside the range of 64 bit IEEE 754.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer And if you don't want the capture groups you could try with `^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$`